# The imported type 'XXXXXX' is defined multiple times | Xamarin

Tags: ios, dll, xamarin, barcode

I need to generate a barcode image. I worked with onBarcode and ZXing libraries. Both libraries require a methodology to draw barcode. To draw, they require System.Drawing.Graphics and System.Drawing.Bitmap, respectively.

In Xamarin, we get inbuilt System.Drawing dll with monotouch library. But unfortunately it implements only six methods ie Point, PointF, Rectangle, RectangleF, Size and SizeF. We need to have a dll which implements all drawing methods. So, I downloaded a System.Drawing dll and added to the reference.

But now, I get a compile time error which says " The imported type 'System.Drawing.SizeF' is defined multiple times".

Please suggest a work around with both the DLLs as I require all other draw methods and not able to remove System.Drawing dll from monotouch library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more google search and digging out in the library. The error was due to multiple implementation of these functions in both dll file. I was no where to solve it out and neither find a way any where . I googled more an then found zing component for Xamarin:

http://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile

This component worked like a charm. Because in the component you will no longer require bitmap class, it directly gives you UIImage of the barcode.

Hope it will help others.